# Youtube iFrame API - player.getVideoData() disappear from the youtube iframe api

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

It seems that the player.getVideoData() disappear from the player object.
In the official Youtube documentation the method can't be find :
[Official Youtube Developers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

But this usefull method was used to get datas about video like the title as we can see in this ticket for example :
[Get YouTube video info from iFrame embed API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416703/get-youtube-video-info-from-iframe-embed-api)

It seems it disappears the 2017/11/14 but I don't see release note about this :
[Official Youtube Developers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Revision_History)

Do you have some informations?

Do you know if we have a new way to get the title of the video (from youtube not in our own html)?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: See here for possible solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312027/youtube-iframe-api-player-getvideodata-disappear-from-the-youtube-iframe-api

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by Youtube since the 2017/11/17.

But in the documentation there is still no reference to the player.getVideoData() :
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information

Regards